# Adding swift packages /dependencies without Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, swift-package-manager

I am trying to add swift packages through the command line or any other way. Without using xcode UI.

I need this because we are using Unity and want to migrate from cocoapods to SPM. We need this done via CI systems. I saw that the changes are done inside the xcode project file structure itself -> project.pbxproj. But seems pain to understand and maintain.

Are there any command line tools ?

thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md https://www.raywenderlich.com/1993018-an-introduction-to-swift-package-manager etc ?

Comment: thanks but i can't see a way to add dependency through the swift package thingy.